# Disk shows wrong size after clone from 64GB SSD to a 1TB SSD

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd, clone, m.2

I'm trying to understand the permanently reduced capacity after disk clone.

We cloned from a 64GB SSD to a Transcend M.2 1TB SSD (with SATA adapter) using an [Addonics Disk Duplicator](https://www.addonics.com/category/hdd_duplicator.php) (I guess it does a binary copy like `dd`). After that the 1TB disk's capacity is reduced to 64GB. Notice that it's the CAPACITY seen by BIOS and OS, not the size of any partition, volume, or file system.

I don't see any free space after the 64GB at all, neither in Windows Disk Manager nor in Linux gparted/fdisk/lshw. All partitions are removed and partition tables recreated (GPT or MSDOS), but that did not help. Again, it's not about partitions, it's the capacity.

I have done partition extension and file system resizing before, and none has failed like this. I tried this but it didn't work.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
```

Furthermore, disk is showing a wrong number of cylinders, much less than what it should have.

Any thoughts? Should I blame the SSD or the duplicator? Thanks!

I ran [`hdparm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/hdparm.8.html):

```
hdparm -N -g /dev/sdd
```

And this is the output:

```
geometry = 61057/64/32
sectors - 125045424
start = 0 SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]: 70 00 0b 00 00 00 00 0a 00 .. 00 max sectors = 125045424/1(1?)
HPA setting seems invalid (buggy kernel device driver?)
```

Comment: Addonics Disk Duplicator is a hardware device that clones drives of one exact size to other drives of the same size. It basically does a full partition table copy that has the partition the same size as the source. Thus what you are seeing. This kind issue is fairly common and the best solution would be to use a drive to drive clone from the Linux terminal itself. Look into using [GParted](https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted) to adjust the partition size.

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks for the quick reply. I tried GParted, but it doesn't see spaces beyond 64GB.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks. I tried to wipe everything with `dd ... bs=1G count=1024`, but got `dd: error writing... not enough space` and only 64GB could be written.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for the advice. `hdparm -N -g /dev/sdd` gives following.
` geometry = 61057/64/32, sectors - 125045424, start = 0
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]: 70 00 0b 00 00 00 00 0a 00 .. 00 
max sectors = 125045424/1(1?), HPA setting seems invalid (buggy kernel device driver?)` BTW, I'm using USB-SATA-M2 adapter. Does it matter?

Comment: Hi @Mokubai The size remains the same after a system power cycle.

Comment: @lqu how about the "dco restore" command from https://superuser.com/a/642765/19943

Comment: Instead of a comment provide all relevant information in the question body.

Comment: hdparm output gives a clue: the HPA. Check user guide for that device (link does not work for me BTW) and see if it offers settings for modifying HPA.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a faulty disk, which may have been faulty before or *by design*. SSDs need to store a lot of metadata for the controller firmware to work (block mapping tables, actual flash configuration etc.).

If the on-drive management firmware or the flash itself (or even the power supply) is faulty, the enduring write process may have damaged or even partly overwritten drive-internal meta information on reserved parts of the flash memory, thus changing the drive specs or management data forever.

By specification, that should never happen by user operation alone. You are free to write any visible sector you want, with any data you want.