# Can the HPA and DCA contain user data from the filesystem?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, security, secure-erase, hdparm

The [HPA and DCO](https://support.blancco.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=66244) are hidden areas on some drives that can be used to install [firmware-based malware](https://www.wired.com/2015/02/nsa-firmware-hacking) or deliberately hide some files.
Tools like `hdparm` [can be used](https://superuser.com/a/642765/323079) to wipe these areas, as can [most commercial solutions](https://support.blancco.com/display/KB/Report+messages+related+to+hidden+area+handling).

However, no sources I've come across explain the feasibility of these areas containing remnants of actual user data that hasn't been deliberately concealed there - in other words, data that has only been written to the filesystem.

Or to put this in a more practical way: can a user securely wiping a drive of just user data (i.e. with no suspicion of malware) safely avoid wiping these hidden areas, or is it possible for user data to naturally "leak" into these areas from the filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HPA and DCO areas are protected by the disk firmware and are not available to the operating system. They are different than the spare sectors in an SSD drive which are used during normal disk operation.
Those areas can have user information ONLY if the user stored the data there on porpouse. Those actions can be only performed using specialized software like ATATOOL[1](https://www.forensicfocus.com/forums/general/updated-atatool-software-hpa-dco-bad-sectors-for-windows/).
I have never seen hidden information on those areas, even on forensic investigations from tech savvy users equipment. If you just want to secure wipe a normal user disk, you can ignore HPA and DCO.
Here is an in depth discussion that you can read: [ForensicFocus](https://www.forensicfocus.com/forums/forensic-software/hdd-wiping/paged/2/#post-6586323)